# Replace strings that start with "X" ,with "Y", in R

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I am trying to take all strings that start with a certain few letters and replace them with a different string.

If I have:

```
y <- "pet"
x <-c("Cat","Cats","Catss")
z=cbind(y,x)
```

Which gives:

```
y      x
pet   Cat
pet   Cats
pet   Catss
```

How can I get

```
y      x
pet    Cat
pet    Cat
pet    Cat
```

Comment: won't z[,2] <- 'Cat' work?

Comment: @KarthikS it would for this example, doubt it would for their real usecase.

Comment: Please provide realistic example data, what is the rule here? What happens if you have other values in Y, and other values in X, as dog, Dogs, Dogz, aDog, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub(pattern = "^Cat.*", replacement = "Cat", x)
```

for more complex patterns you should take a look on [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Answer (score 0):

```
sub("(Cat).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "Cat" "Cat" "Cat"
```

This solution uses backreference: `sub`'s *replacement* argument (i.e. the second) 'recalls' only the capturing group in the *pattern* argument (i.e, the first), here `(Cat)` but not the endings thus effectively removing them.